# convert prolog input `(a,z,b)` to `[a,z,b]`

Tags: prolog, dcg

I am new to prolog.

I need to convert the prolog input which is a given variable in the format of coma separated values inside open and close brace `(a,z,b)` to a prolog list of the form `[a,z,b]` .

Can some one please help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main functor of a sequence is ,/2, of a list is ./2. Hence,

```
% call: convert(+Sequence,-List)
convert(','(A,B), [A|B1]) :- !, convert(B,B1).
convert(A,[A]).
```

I assume that elements of the sequence should not be converted:

```
?- convert((1,2,3),L).
L = [1, 2, 3].

?- convert((1,(2,3),4),L).
L = [1, (2, 3), 4].
```

Answer (score 2):

In addition to what Alexander wrote above: As often when describing lists, DCGs are a good fit also in this case, especially if you also want to flatten tuples within the tuple:

```
tuple_list((A,B)) --> !, tuple_list(A), tuple_list(B).
tuple_list(A)     --> [A].
```

The second case that Alexander mentioned now works (just in case you want this):

```
?- phrase(tuple_list((1,(2,3),4)), Ls).
Ls = [1, 2, 3, 4].
```

I suppose you do not need this in your use case, but if you do, consider using this DCG notation. Other than that, this tuple representation is called "defaulty" because it needs a "default" case (second rule) to process it, and this is not very nice because it prevents you from using the predicate in both directions. It is cleaner to use dedicated functors to describe the different cases. For example, use a term like triple(a,b,c) instead of (a,b,c) to represent a triple, a list to represent a sequence of arbitrary length etc., and the conversion predicates will be a lot more declarative and usable in all directions.